# Git is stonewalling me at every turn: I cannot commit to my project

Tags: git, github

So I'm coming back to project I haven't used in months, and something is clearly wrong:

```
git push origin master
```

gives me the response:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/username/project.git'
```

So, I google this error, and get redirected to a bunch of other StackOverflow questions, all of which just generate errors when I try and run the commands suggested.

I am willing to try anything, and I wish I could explain myself better, but I simply don't understand enough about Git to do so.

Where do I start?

Comment: What `git branch -avv` returns? And `git log`? Do you have at least one commit in your local repo?

Comment: Can you verify that the remote branch exists on GitHub?  You can check this from the comfort of your web browser.

Comment: @VonC git branch -avv returns `remotes/origin/master adc353e Update README.md` which matches my last commit to GitHub. git log returns `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`

Comment: How about `git log --all`

Comment: git log --all returns: `commit adc353e95b662771ad446590a0df7f037086bcae
Author: Me <me@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Feb 21 21:07:56 2015 +1300

    Update README.md

commit 26a9e28aa834357be9eb865790e429f34eef21d7
Author: Me <me@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Feb 21 21:03:23 2015 +1300

    Update README.md

commit a17a679cd640e20f64c93859680260e0af0a44bb
Author: Me <me@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Feb 21 20:59:12 2015 +1300

    Initial commit`

Comment: Type `git branch -a` to see all branches (local and remote).  Do you see `master` as both a local _and_ remote branch?

Comment: `git branch -a` returns `* master <newline in here>
  
remotes/origin/master`? Is that of any use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> git log returns fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'

This is typical of an empty repo.
Since origin is there, try and create your master branch at the same commit as origin/master (save any work in progress first):

```
git branch master origin/master
git checkout master
```

Comment: `git branch master origin/master` returns `Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.`. Then, `git checkout master` returns `error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
 README.md
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting`

Comment: @EchoLogic to be one the safe side, try `git stash`, before the `git checkout` command.

Comment: `git branch master origin/master` now returns `fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists`. Followed by: `git stash`, which gives `Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: adc353e Update README.md
HEAD is now at adc353e Update README.md`. Then `git checkout master` returns: `Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.`

Comment: @EchoLogic you already did the git branch, no need to repeat it.

Comment: @EchoLogic Now that you are on master, you can add, commit and push!

Comment: okay, so I ran "git push origin master", and I get the response "Everything is up to date" (thanks!), but my local directory is still differing from my GitHub project?

Comment: @Echo as I said, you need to add and ximmit first.

Comment: I get you. Thanks for the help! Also thanks to @TimBiegeleisen for the help.